# How to perform statistical computations in a query?

Tags: sql-server, distribution, statistics

I have a table which is filled with float values. I need to calculate the number of results grouped by their distribution around the mean value ([Gaussian Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_distribution)). Basically, it is calculated like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), FloatColumn - AVG(FloatColumn) - STDEV(FloatColumn) 
FROM Data 
GROUP BY FloatColumn - AVG(FloatColumn) - STDEV(FloatColumn)
```

But for obvious reasons, SQL Server gives this error: `Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.`

My question is, can I somehow leave this computation to SQL Server? Or do I have to do it the old fashioned way? Retrieve all the data, and do the calculation myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the aggregate of the whole set you can use an empty `OVER` clause

```
WITH T(Result)
     AS (SELECT FloatColumn - Avg(FloatColumn) OVER() - Stdev(FloatColumn) OVER ()
         FROM   Data)
SELECT Count(*),
       Result
FROM   T
GROUP  BY Result
```

Comment: I didn't get the `OVER` part. If I have a `WHERE` clause, does it have to be repeated in the `OVER` function or something?

Comment: Don't mind previous comment. Found an excellent article about over: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-sever-2005-using-over-with-aggregate-functions

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db484/3)

You can perform a pre-aggregation of the data, and join back to the table.

**Schema Setup**:

```
create table data(floatcolumn float);
insert data values
  (1234.56),
  (134.56),
  (134.56),
  (234.56),
  (1349),
  (900);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) C, D.FloatColumn - A
  FROM
    (
    SELECT AVG(FloatColumn) + STDEV(FloatColumn) A
        FROM Data
    ) preagg
CROSS JOIN Data D
GROUP BY FloatColumn - A;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db484/3/0)**:

```
| C |           COLUMN_1 |
--------------------------
| 2 | -1196.876067819572 |
| 1 | -1096.876067819572 |
| 1 |  -431.436067819572 |
| 1 |   -96.876067819572 |
| 1 |    17.563932180428 |
```

Comment: If you have a WHERE clause, it goes into both the derived table (subquery) and the main query as well.